# How to get all bounced and rejected emails in AWS

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am able to send email using SES (Simple Email Service) in sandbox environment , but i want to get all the emails which were bounced,rejected or had any sort of complain.
Can you please tell me in detail about the configuration and Code ( C# language) needed.
I am using  asp.net with C#.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a configuration set in SES through which you can track all the events happen to your sent email, configuration sets currently supports three event destinations

- cloudwatch
- SNS
- Firehose

you can choose any of them based on your requirement SES will send the payload for your desired event for example and event for bounce email etc.

I'm posting a screenshot in which i have configured SES configuration set to track emails which are open and deliver the event on cloudwatch and SNS.

[image: SES configuration set]

for more information you can refer to AWS documentation

[SES configuration Set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-configuration-sets.html)